# rxjs: how to improve this case by rxjs operators in a functional reactive programming style?

Tags: rxjs

In my case, I have a function as following:

```
  private transformResData(data: Data[]): DataInfo[] {
    let userIDNames: Array<OBJIDName>;
    this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$.subscribe((res) => {
      userIDNames = res;   
    })
    return data.map((each) => {
      return {
        id: each.id,
        userName: userIDNames.find(current => current.userId === each.referID).userName
      };
    })       
  }
```

simply  speaking,  this function want to map the input data to a new form, and the output data containing a property `userName`, and input data only has property `referId`. I need to map `referId` to `userName`. Simple, yes?

And as you can see, the mapping relationship is obtained by rxjs as an Observable:

```
this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$ // Observable<Array<UserIDName>> of the id and name mapping
```

My current solution can work by `subscribe` to the Observable and get the data.

But I want to know how to do this in a more functional reactive programming way. My imagination is using rxjs operators like:

```
this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$.pipe(...)
```

The function still need to return plain array data instead of Observable. 
How to do this? Thank you

Comment: You can't really return plain data if this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$ is a async call. Need to return Observable<youdata>. If fact if this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$ is aysnc your current code won't work

Comment: It's not async. In fact it the return of store.select of ngrx. I didn't mention it in the origin post

Comment: It is not a good practise to be honest. Observable can be either async or sync there's not 100% guarantee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to return an Observable or Promise, I removed the local variables and pass variable along the function chain.

```
private transformResData(data: Data[]): Observable<DataInfo[]> {
   return this.dataStoreService.userIDNames$.pipe(map(userIDNames => {
       return data.map((each) => ({
           id: each.id,
           userName: userIDNames.find(current => current.userId === each.referID).userName
         })
       })       
    }))
}
```

Comment: thank you. ignore the return value type, it's what I want.

Comment: Glad it helps. You can further flatten this chain, if you wise